# The calculator I am making using iOS cannot print out the correct number

Tags: ios, objective-c, calculator

I am making a calculator using Xcode iOS SDK 6.1. However, I have faced a problem because my calculator cannot add the two numbers together. It seems that the calculator always give me the first number as an answer. Is there a way to solve the problem?

Here's the code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"


@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize FirstNumber,SecondNumber;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.FirstNumber.delegate = self;
    self.SecondNumber.delegate = self;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [FirstNumber release];
    [SecondNumber release];

    [super dealloc];
}

- (IBAction)Calculate:(id)sender
{
    NSString *finalNumberString;
    int firstNumberInt, secondNumberInt, finalNumberInt;

    firstNumberInt = [FirstNumber.text integerValue];
    secondNumberInt = [SecondNumber.text integerValue];

    finalNumberInt = firstNumberInt + secondNumberInt;


    UIAlertView *alerting = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Answer" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The answer is %d",finalNumberInt] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [alerting show];

    _FinalNumber.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i",finalNumberInt];

}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField
{
    [FirstNumber resignFirstResponder];
    [SecondNumber resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if ([touch view] == self.view)
    {
        [FirstNumber resignFirstResponder];
        [SecondNumber resignFirstResponder];

    }
}
@end
```

Comment: Have you added any logging to track the process or debugged?

Comment: I agree with @DrummerB answer, but as a side note, you should follow the convention of naming properties and instance variables with a lowercase initial. So you shouldn't use **FirstNumber** or **_FirstNumber** but you should use **firstNumber** and **_firstNumber** instead. Capitalized strings should be used for class names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIAlertView *alerting = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Answer" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The answer is %d",secondNumberInt] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles: nil];
```

**secondNumberInt** looks like it should be **finalNumberInt**

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you're showing the wrong value in the alert.

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The answer is %d",secondNumberInt]
```

This should probably be

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The answer is %d", finalNumberInt]
```

instead.

Comment: I tried it with final number but the answer gives me the same answer as the first number

Comment: interface ViewController : UIViewController
property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *FirstNumber;
property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *SecondNumber;
property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *FinalNumber; Pardon me the at sign because stackoverflow doesn't allow me to put

- (IBAction)Calculate:(id)sender;

Answer (score 1):

**Incorrect values used as make the Alert message,**

```
    UIAlertView *alerting = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Answer" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The answer is %d",secondNumberInt] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alerting show];
```

**Change that part like this,**

```
    UIAlertView *alerting = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Answer" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The answer is %d",finalNumberInt] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alerting show];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to put an NSLog between the two integer casts, and check if strings are read fine or if one of them is zero. If one of them is zero, probably you haven't connected the outlet to the UITextField in interface builder, or maybe you are just typing some weird string in the textfield: since you are casting to integer, you obiouvsly shouldn't put decimal digits.

```
firstNumberInt = [FirstNumber.text integerValue];
secondNumberInt = [SecondNumber.text integerValue];

NSLog(@"FirstNumber string %@ integer %d", FirstNumber.text, firstNumberInt);
NSLog(@"SecondNumber string %@ integer %d", SecondNumber.text, secondNumberInt);

finalNumberInt = firstNumberInt + secondNumberInt;
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess I didn't connect the UITextField to ViewController.h properly. I fixed it by reconnecting again.

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark my answer as the right one, and if you want upvote it.

Comment: Sorry @DrummerB, I was writing my answer when you added your comment, I didn't want to steal your answer :)